# Two jquery function on click for one button

Tags: jquery, click

I have a case need to create two function onclick for one button, it can't work together.

```
<a href="#" id="#button1">button</a>
```

In my page loaded javascript resources from outsite to handle an event for this button:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){ alert('1');})
```

But for now, i need to customize to handle more actions when click this button. So, i need add one more jquery on click for this button to do that:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){ alert('2');});
```

So, is there any problem with that?

Comment: you need two different jQuery functions to run when 1 button is clicked?

Comment: you can do `$("#button1").click(function(){ func1(); func2();})`

Comment: Side note: Use `console.log()` instead of alert

Comment: Yes, i know about that. Just in this case, because the first handle event loaded from 3rd-party, it has been created a function to handle event onclick on there. And on my site, i would like to create the new one to handle the other event. I want to handle both events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, on my way, it works fine on chrome/safari.
Just a problem on Firefox, i guess that,maybe firefox and webkit using different engine. So that, on firefox, it can't order which click function run in first and second.

Answer (score 1):

While not ideal, there's no problem with the code that you posted. Multiple event handlers can be bound to a single event using jquery, and they will execute in the order that they were bound to the event.

From http://api.jquery.com/on/ :

> Event handlers bound to an element are called in the same order that they were bound.

Comment: Yes, i know about that. Just in this case, because the first event hadnle loaded from 3rd-party, on that, it has been create a function to handle event onclick. And on my site, i would like to create the new one to handle the other event. I want to handle both events.

Comment: Can i use .on() to attached more event handle for one button?